# Enable hardware encryption in Bacula with LTO-7

Tags: encryption, bacula

Does Bacula support encryption by using the AES-chip which is integrated in LTO-7 Tapedrive?
Or is there a plugin like "stenc" that could be integrated in Bacula?

Comment: I really don't want to advertise here, but we've used Bareos (a fork of bacula) with LTO encryption successfully. Everything is built into the bareos-sd and bareos-dir without the need for any scripting.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work with the use of a tape library, by modifying the autochanger script to set the encryption key after each tape had been loaded into the drive.

I did this by modifying `/etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer` and changing the `load` condition to enable encryption before returning:

```
load)
  ...
  stenc -f $device -e on -a 1 -k /path/to/my.key
  exit $rtn
;;
```

I am not sure exactly how you could do it if you don't have a tape library, as the drive can only have an encryption key set when there is a tape loaded.  Possibly you would have to manually run `stenc` after inserting each tape.